# Execute git pre-commit hook only if files in certain directory modified

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to create a bash script for a git pre-commit hook. Whenever a commit is made, I want to check if files in a certain directory are part of the staged files and if so, run a command (Grunt task). So far I have everything working, except for only running if certain files are modified. I'm trying to get this to work:

```
SRC_PATTERN="site/assets/js/"
if [ grep --quiet $SRC_PATTERN `git diff --cached --name-only` ]
then
  echo "none"
  exit 0
fi
```

This is unfortunately giving me errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try,

```
git diff --cached --name-only | if grep --quiet "$SRC_PATTERN"
then
    ...
```

Happy hacking

Answer (score 14):

Try it like this:

```
SRC_PATTERN="site/assets/js/"
if git diff --cached --name-only | grep --quiet "$SRC_PATTERN"
then
  echo "none"
  exit 0
fi
```

This looks a lot like the accepted answer, but that one is wrong. In bash/sh each command in a pipeline is executed in a separate subshell, so an exit in the then part will only exit the subshell, any code that follows the fi will still be executed!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the git builtin `git diff --cached --quiet -- "$SRC_PATTERN"`.

`--quiet` implies `--exit-code`, which makes git exit with code `0` if unchanged.

`$SRC_PATTEN` can contain * to match on anything (including `/`). For example `*/tests/*.py` would match `backend/tests/src/main.py`.

Example:

```sh
if git diff --cached --quiet -- "backend/*.py"; then
    echo "Unchanged"
else
    echo "Changed"
fi
```